# Optimizing an NHibernate query

Tags: nhibernate, optimization

I've got the following piece of code which (obviously) gives me HUGE performance problems, and I seek an advice on how to make it better. The idea is, for each base item in a list, I look if there is at least one derived item, and if not, I create one. The problem is, for each base item there's a separate database query:

```
var derivedItems = from item in baseItems select item.GetDerivedItem(session);
```

where

```
public virtual DerivedListItem GetDerivedItem(ISession session)
{
    var items = session.Query<DerivedItem>()
                       .Where(item => item.BaseItem == this);
    if (items.Any())
        return items.First();
    var newItem = new DerivedItem(this);
    session.Save(newItem);
    return newItem;
}
```

How would you improve this kind of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Criteria, you can add an alias to the criteria to prefetch the joins for your query.

It would go something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria.For(GetType(MyQueriedType)).CreateAlias("DerivedItem", "d", SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```

Obviously, you can then proceed to get further info from other tables by repeasting the process. Don't forget to map the next alias to any potential alias.

---

As a matter of fact, if you're reluctant to stop using linq to nhibernate, i'd recommend looking into joins for linq to nhibernate. Perhaps [this post](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/linq-to-nhibernate-progress-report-a-christmas-gift.aspx) can help

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give it a try

Comment: When I use DetachedCriteria.For(GetType(MyQueriedType)), I get all items of the particular type. But how do I do the same if I have a root entity and a collection valued property to filter from?